# Parsing strings with split JAVA

Tags: java

I'm trying to find an object in a list from a text file

Example:

- L;10;€10,50;83259875;YellowPaint
- -H;U;30;€12,00;98123742;Hammer
- G;U;80;€15,00;87589302;Seeds

By inserting 98123742 by input with scanner, i want to find that string. 
I tried to do this:

```
private static void inputCode() throws IOException {

        String code;
        String line = null;
        boolean retVal = false;
        System.out.println("\ninsert code: ");
        code = in.next();
        try {

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("SHOP.txt");


            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] token = line.split(";");

                if (token[0].equals(code) && token[1].equals(code)) {
                    retVal = true;
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }


            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("impossible open the file " + fileName);
        }
         catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(
                    "Error reading file '" 
                    + fileName + "'");                  

            }
           System.out.println(retVal);
        }
```

How can i print  "-H;U;30;€12,00;98123742;Hammer" inserting "98123742" (that is the code of the product) ?

Comment: after splitting `String[] token` contains 6 items, and you have to check `token[4]` but not `token[0]` or `token[1]`

Comment: i tried as you said, like: **if (token[4].equals(code))** but gives me this error : **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4**

Comment: It means that some of the lines has less values. Do all lines match the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you splitting in the first place? For such a simple usecase, and with that line format, I'd go with

```
line.contains(";" + code);
```

Not much else to do.

Comment: It will lead to wrong result if price or another value will match `code`

Comment: @Ruslan You're right, but that's why I wrote "with that line format"

Comment: @LppEdd You saved my life. Thank you!

Comment: @RaijinKensei I've also updated the answer. That's a more secure way.

Comment: @LppEdd consider this: `(";" + line + ";").contains(";" + code + ";")` as more secured. Also `code` is returned by `in.next()` so it is a `String`, does not need `String.valueOf(code)`.

Comment: @LppEdd What about for summing quantity and price of every string returning the total value of the inventory? could i use the same method?